# How to get do.call to return an object rather than a function call?

Tags: r

I am using `do.call` to call a regression function (of the user's choice; e.g. `lm()`, `glm()` ), and would like it to return the resulting regression object (of, say, class `lm`) that I could then work further with, rather than a function call. Is this possible?

A quick example:

I would like code like the following:

```
reg.fun <- lm
reg.object.A <- do.call(reg.fun, list(formula=formula.reg, data=data.A, ...)))
```

to return the same object as

```
reg.object.A <- lm(formula = formula.reg, data = data.A)
```

Comment: it **does** return an object, just an ugly one with the `call` slot expanded/evaluated ... try `cc <- do.call(...); cc$call <- quote(junk)`

Comment: @BenBolker Does it bother you if i post your comments as answers? I get annoyed when browsing unanswered questions only to learn that it has been answered in the comments. I doubt either of us care about the reputation at this point. Do you want a certain grace period incase you want to write something up?

Comment: @MrFlick, Agreed. You can always post the answer and mark it as "community wiki".

Comment: By the way, the method described by @AnandaMahto is considered to be a [meta-approved](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) way of doing this. Looks like a win-win scenario as far as no one cares about the rep.

Comment: @MrFlick, that's fine.  I usually post possible answers as comments because they're incomplete or I'm not sure about them.  I'm happy if someone makes them into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear (since it was foggy to me at first :-) ),  `bar<-do.call(lm, etc...)` returns the same object as  `rab <- lm( same formula and data)` :

```
 y=2:6
 x=1:5
 rab<-lm(y~x)
 bar<-do.call(foofun,list(formula='y~x',data=list(x=1:5,y=2:6)))


for(j in names(bar) ) print(identical(bar$j,rab$j))
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `for(j in names(bar) ) print(identical(bar[[j]],rab[[j]]))` doesn't returns the same